# Allocating a Java heap for Tomcat on an EC2 instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, heap-memory

I'm writing a Java servlet that I'm planning to deploy on Amazon AWS using Elastic Beanstalk. My tests show that things run well using a Small EC2 instance using their stock Tomcat AMI that Beanstalk uses.

I'm trying to figure out how to properly allocate Java heap space for this configuration. A Small instance has 1.7 GB of memory, so I'm thinking that a 1024MB heap will work well. I realize that memory will be needed for other things even though the only "real" purpose of this instance is to run Tomcat. And I also know that there's some point with large heaps where the standard Sun/Oracle JVM doesn't really work.

Is this a reasonable way to allocate the memory? Should I be using more or less? What tools can I use to help determine the optimal configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1024 seems ok, maybe a bit much.

I'm not exactly sure what your servlet is doing, but to give you an idea, I have an ecommerce application with about 1000 daily users running on 2 small ec2 instances. Tomcat load is distributed via mod_jk.

I did not tune the JVM at all and kept the default settings.  I'm also using terracotta distributed object caching, and that process seems to be consuming most of the memory.

Are you deployed on a linux based os or windows?  IMO, linux does a better job at managing available memory.

As to tools, I would suggest deploying your application as is to a small ec2 instance and using a tool like JMeter to stress test the application.  During the stress test, you can have the top utility open(assuming your app is on linux and top is installed).

Try to break your application by seeing how much load it can handle.  That's the beauty of ec2, you can setup a test environment in minutes and discard it right after.

Comment: Thanks for your input. 

I won't go into detail about our app. It allows users to view information about different topics, and then possibly add more information to them. Some of the information about the topics is dynamically generated from a database while most of it is static data that we read in from files at startup and is held in our own data structures on the heap. All together, it's about 250-300 MB worth of data. I'm guessing that when we really get running we'll have a few tens of thousands of users a day.

Comment: On my previous AWS project I tried to control everything. For this project I decided I needed to spend more time on the "real" application and how to market it and not simple IT jobs, so I'm simply using stock Beanstalk. That means using their stock AMI which is Linux, and Elastic Load Balancer. Is there some reason why you're using mod_jk to distribute load instead of ELB?

So given this, why do you think 1024 is a bit too much? That leaves 700MB for everything else, which is actually nothing other than standard operating system tasks. Am I looking at this correctly?

Comment: @SanderSmith I'm still using the ELB but I am using that to balance between 2 small apache web server instances.  Then mod_jk is used from my apache web server instances to distribute load to my tomcat instances.  Apache is better at serving static resources and handles SSL better, thats why I am using them.  I guess the best thing you can do is test load and make your decisions from there.  If your application is expecting to receive 10k users a day, I don't think a small ec2 instance will suffice no matter how you tune the JVM

Answer (score 0):

Check newrelic for java to determine you heap usage pattern.